# Is there a way to use container registry images in dockerfiles?

Tags: docker, gitlab, dockerfile, gitlab-ci

I am currently trying to build docker images in Gitlab CI. Here I am trying to use an image from the Gitlab container registry to build the image.

```
FROM <CI_REGISTRY>/<CI_PROJECT_ROOT_NAMESPACE>/<CI_PROJECT_NAME>/<image_name>

RUN echo 'hello world'
```

executed with

```
test:
 stage: build
 image: docker
 services: 
   - docker:dind
 before_script:
   - docker login -u "$CI_REGISTRY_USER" -p "$CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD" $CI_REGISTRY
 script:
   - docker build --pull -t $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE/test:latest .
   - docker push $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE/test:latest
```

is not able to build the image, as the manifest is unknown.

What is the best way of doing this? Pulling the image in the job before building the image does feel not right to me.

Thank you

Comment: where is ur Dockerfile in docker build command ?

Comment: for this minimal example I put it into the root folder of the repository. The build command executes, but it struggles to find the image i am trying to use within it.

Comment: most probably your are not using correct image name in docker file or its tag is wrong or maybe path

Answer (score 2):

I think you might read this :
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#understand-how-arg-and-from-interact

then your docker file may start like :

```
ARG CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE_FULL_NAME
FROM ${CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE_FULL_NAME}
```

then your call to docker build may look like :

```
script:
   - > docker build --pull 
       --build-arg CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE_FULL_NAME=$CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE_FULL_NAME
       -t $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE/test:latest .
```

Do not confuse CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE_FULL_NAME the name of the base image, with $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE/test:latest which will be the new image name